# Failed token purchase transactions on uniswap with web3.py

Tags: web3js, web3.py, uniswap, python

I'm getting failed transactions(reverted) when I try to buy tokens from uniswap v2 using the swapExactEthForToken method in my build transaction with web3.py. I have added my code below.
I have tried this on ropsten, rinkeby and even mainnet.
I have test ETH on both test networks also.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
from web3 import Web3
import json
import config
import time
import pprint


infura_url = config.INFURA_URL_TESTNET
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

print(web3.isConnected())

# uniswap address and abi
uniswap_router = '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'
uniswap_factory = web3.toChecksumAddress('0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f')
uniswapABI = 'I pasted the uniswap v2 abi here'
uniswap_factory_abi = json.loads(uniswapABI)



sender_address = "0x39DC57cf562736D62bE25EFC1B37ce43dEaf51Bc"

balance = web3.eth.get_balance(sender_address)
eth_bal = web3.fromWei(balance, 'ether')
print('My Test Eth Balance is: ', eth_bal)

tokenToBuy = web3.toChecksumAddress("0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984")
spend = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab")  # wbnb contract


# Setup the Uniswap contract
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=uniswap_factory, abi=uniswap_factory_abi)

nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)


start = time.time()


uniswapv2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
    10000000000,  # set to 0, or specify minimum amount of tokeny you want to receive - consider decimals!!!
    [spend, tokenToBuy],
    sender_address,
    (int(time.time()) + 100000)
).buildTransaction({
    'from': sender_address,
    'value': web3.toWei(0.01, 'ether'),  
    'gas': 2000000,
    'nonce': nonce,
})

signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(uniswapv2_txn, private_key=config.private)
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(web3.toHex(tx_token))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the router address and not the factory address to execute a trade....

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

*Contract_Address* = **0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D**

```
from web3 import Web3
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import time
import os
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware


load_dotenv()

infura_url = os.getenv("INFURA_URL")
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

print(web3.isConnected())

# uniswap address and abi
abi = json.load(open('abi.json'))
address = '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)

sender_address = "0x5A9cBc9821cF17eC0823593b6a2daD9e72a053BC"

balance = web3.eth.get_balance(sender_address)
eth_bal = web3.fromWei(balance, 'ether')
print('My Test Eth Balance is: ', eth_bal)

tokenToBuy = web3.toChecksumAddress("0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984")   #Uni Token Address
spend = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab")  # wbnb contract # weth Token address

nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)

uniswapv2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
    10000000000,  # set to 0, or specify minimum amount of tokeny you want to receive - consider decimals!!!
    [spend, tokenToBuy],
    sender_address,
    (int(time.time()) + 100000)
).buildTransaction({
    'from': sender_address,
    'value': web3.toWei(0.1, 'ether'),  
    'gas': 2000000,
    'nonce': nonce,
})

signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(uniswapv2_txn, private_key=os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY"))
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(web3.toHex(tx_token))
```

Comment: You should add an explanation about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the factory contract instead of the router. Take a look at this code, with comments!

> Note that I did not specify the token to buy, and this is based on mainnet ETH.

Keep in mind that these contracts on testnets often have issues, especially thinking that [Ropsten and Rinkeby are considered deprecated](https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/06/21/testnet-deprecation/). Also, you could use an environment variable for the private key to be safer.

```py
from web3 import Web3
import json
import time

# Define the node URL and connection
node_url = "YOUR_NODE_URL"

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(node_url))

# verify the connection is successful
if web3.isConnected():
    print("Connection Successful")
else:
    print("Connection Failed")

# reconstruct contract in python
router_address = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"
uniswap_abi = "[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_WETH","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"WETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountADesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveB","type":"uint256"}],"name":"quote","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapETHForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]"

uniswap_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=router_address, abi=uniswap_abi)


# define the sender address and prints the balance (in ETH)
sender_address = "YOUR_ADDRESS_HERE"
private_key = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY"
balance = web3.eth.get_balance(sender_address)
print("This address has:", web3.fromWei(balance, "ether"), "ETH")

# specify token to buy
token_to_buy = web3.toChecksumAddress("TOKEN_ADDRESS")

# specifty token to spend (WETH mainnet)
spend = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2")

# get nonce for the sender address
nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender_address)

start = time.time()  # start of the tx

# call solidity function
uniswap_tx = uniswap_contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
    0, [spend, token_to_buy], sender_address, (int(time.time()) + 10000)
).build_transaction(
    {
        "from": sender_address,
        "value": web3.toWei(0.1, "ether"),
        "gas": 2000000,
        "gasPrice": web3.toWei("10", "gwei"),
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
)

# sign transaction
sign_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
    uniswap_tx, private_key
)  # use the private key to sign the transaction

# send transaction
tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(sign_tx.rawTransaction)

# get transaction confirmation and print hash
print(web3.toHex(tx_hash))
```